# jquery autocomplete: works for first value, how to enable it for next?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete so user can easly enter data on inputs, like this:

```
 <?
$a = new etiqueta(0, '');
$b = $a->autocomplete_etiquetas();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cargar_autocomplete_etiquetas(){
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: [<? echo $b; ?>]
        });
    }
</script>
```

$a =  *$b* its an  *array*  with a result like:  'help','please',i','need','to,'be able to', 'select next item',' with autocomplete';

and i checked the ui documentation, but it doesn't fith with my source method.. any idea?
I'm trying like this (edited with Bugai13 aportation):

```
 <?
$a = new etiqueta(0, '');
$b = $a->autocomplete_etiquetas();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cargar_autocomplete_etiquetas(){
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: [<? echo $b; ?>],
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: ", ",
        matchContains: true
    });
}

</script>
```

but i don't know how to do it.. any idea? are .push and .pop functions from the autocomplete? or shall i define, them?

thanks again!

PS: i'm getting adicted to this site!
PS: come on dudes, i think the answer will be very usefull for many people
PS: is it allowed to offer paypal reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've use following to get work multiple autocomplete for tags with ',' separator, hope this help your:

It's full my code that work. In my case in parse function items it just json array, try to  add parse method:

```
   $("#txtTags").autocomplete(UrlFactory.TAGS_AUTOCOMPLETE_URL, {
    matchContains: true,
    width: 320,
    max: 10,
    highlight: false,
    multiple: true,
    multipleSeparator: ", ",
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    dataType: "json",
    parse: function (data) {
        var result = Result.fromJson(data);

        var items = result.getJson("Tags");
        var arr;
        if (items != null)
            arr = items.split(",");
        return $.map(arr, function (row, i) {
            return {
                data: row,
                value: row,
                result: row
            }
        });
    },
    onItemSelect: function () {

    },
    formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
        if (value != null) {
            value = ltrim(value);
            value = rtrim(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
});
```

So, you need something like this:

```
function cargar_autocomplete_etiquetas(){
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: [<? echo $b; ?>],
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: ", ",
        matchContains: true
    });
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaalmost... :(

the autocomplete stil works, but it doesn't add the ", " on select, and it doen't enable autocomplete for next tag...

thanks anyways..

Comment: Ohh man seems i somehow modified plugin to get multiselect work. If need i can send my js and you can compare with yours version. Also try first add parse function.

Comment: what do you mean by  add parse function? any info wil be helpfull :) 

thanks! -EDIT- oh i see, but i'm not using json...

Answer (score 0):

What does `echo $b;` print? I would expect you would need something like `echo implode(',', $b)`, or even `echo '"' . implode('", "', $b) . '"';` to make this work, if $b really is a PHP array.

Edit: (of course I'm only assuming you're using PHP, but if it `<?`s like PHP and `$`s like PHP...)

Comment: the autocomlete works, 
as i said, $b contain a string from my tags separated by comma...
what i want it's that when a user select a tag by autocomplete (or not, typing), he has de posibiliti to keep typing and add another tag with autocomplete (this is what i don't know how to do)
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, right! I didn't get that from your question at all! But apparently @Bugai13 did, and his answer looks good, so I'll leave you to it :)